# Unit testing parts of the application that use Thread Local

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, thread-local

I am trying to implement unit testing in a web application and certain parts of it use [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

I cannot figure out how to go about testing it.

It looks like Junit runs all its tests using a single thread, namely the main thread.

I need to be able to assign different values to my ThreadLocal variable.

Has anyone come across such a scenario ? What do you guys recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Groboutils has support for running multi-threaded tests, which will allow you to test your ThreadLocal variables.

http://groboutils.sourceforge.net/testing-junit/using_mtt.html

Answer (score 1):

I would simply start threads within my unit test.

I recommend you use [`Futures`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and execute them using a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: Would not that affect the transactional nature of your tests ? My understanding is that the transaction is bound to the current thread of execution. I am speaking about spring transactional unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to adorn the respective test methods with a timeout, i.e. `@Test(timeout=100)`. Please note the "THREAD SAFETY WARNING" in [Test::timeout](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html) , especially when you use @BeforeClass and @After annotations.