# How best to utilize a junit test for classes that expect ThrreadLocal variables to have been setup?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5, thread-local-storage

I found a very old question asking the same thing ([Unit testing parts of the application that use Thread Local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498466/unit-testing-parts-of-the-application-that-use-thread-local) ) but it only has 3 answers despite its age and those recomnded differnet frameworks.  Does junit5 (or even junit4) offer a better solution?

to restate the problem, If a class expects to be called only from threads started in the application and expects threadlocals to have been established

```
    class workers implments runnable {
    ...
    public static ThreadLocal<String> myString = new ThreadLocal<String>... 
    ...
    }
    class foo {
        public static calledByJunitAndApp {
            ..myString.get()..
        }
    }
```

then what is the cleaneest and easiets way to establish the expected environment for a junit test that never goes through the runnable but that calls some class that expects it?   The "easiest" part is key since this is for junit tests where the classes they call did not previiously access ThreadLocals, but now do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show what you are trying to do, how you have tried it and what the problems are.

Comment: Using the thread-local  var in the test before calling the Code under test looks like an easy option. Does it not work in your case?

Comment: Using a variable does not create it.  Since the junit tests do not use the Workers class that implements runnable the thread-locals are not created under junit.  I'm thinking I'll have to put those lines into thier own subclass that both the runnable and junit can instantiate.  In junit I could put that into a before class.  That's not too bad.

Comment: oops, that doesn't work since then the utility methods that access the thread locals need to use a differnet class path.

Answer (score 0):

I was making this much more difficult that it actually is (or at least so far that is how it appears :-).  I simply moved the declaration (without initializaion) of the threadLocals to a common globals class and added a setup() method there as well that does the initialization.  The run() method and the junits's @before methods both call it.  After seeing most if not every example that includes a runnable using ThreadLoclas also declare and initialze them there, you get into the rut of thinking you should do it that way as well.

```
    //in the globals packkage
    class globals {
    ...
    public static ThreadLocal<String> myString;
    public static setupTLs() {
        myString = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    }

    //in the main app
    import globals;
    class workers implments runnable {
    ...
    void run() {
        globals.setupTLs();
    }
    class foo {
        public static calledByJunitAndApp {
            ..myString.get()..
        }
    }

    //in junit tests
    import globals;
    @before
    void initializer() {
       globals.setupTLs;
    }
```